# not able to invoke messge bean from restful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, jms, ejb, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create Restful Webservice as a client of Message Driven Bean, But when i invoke the restful method its giving me following error when

```
Connection connection =  connectionFactory.createConnection();

SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.quant.ws.GetConnection.startThread(GetConnection.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

here is the following code:

```
// Inside class declaration
@Resource(mappedName = "jms/testFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(mappedName = "jms/test")
private static Queue queue;
```

Web services Method

```
@GET
@Path("startThread")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String startThread()
{

    try{
    Connection connection =  connectionFactory.createConnection(); // its line number 99
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer( queue);
    Message message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setStringProperty("name", "start");
    producer.send(message);
    }catch(JMSException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
   return "<data>START</data>";
}
```

Do i need to specify anything in sun-web.xml or web.xml ?

Comment: The NullPointerException says it occurs on line 99. Which is line 99 above?

Comment: Connection connection =  connectionFactory.createConnection(); is a line number 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by replacing following code

```
  try{
       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
      queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/test");
      QueueConnectionFactory factory =
      (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/testFactory");
      Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer( queue);

        Message message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setStringProperty("name", "start");
        producer.send(message);

     }
     catch(NamingException e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
     catch(JMSException e){
     System.out.println(e);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your applicationserver setup. Did you inject the connectionFactory somewhere above? Or did a context lookup?

Comment: This should do it provided that your factory and queue are registered with those names.

Answer (score 0):

`connectionFactory` is null. It needs to be initialised somehow.

Comment: Well , i don't have any idea how to do it